# How to return affected number of record of last query in sql

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

In my stored procedure I have used 2 insert statement.When I am executing sp 
using executenonquery(),it return me number of row affected by 2 statement.
Suppose number of row affected by Query 1 is 2 and number of row affected by Query 2 is 3.It returns me 5.I want last query's result.That is 3 only.How to do that?

Comment: Just separate your queries?

Comment: Both query suppose to be in same sp

Comment: Get that into a variable and make the stored proc return that value...

Comment: How will get that into variable so stored procedure can return?

Comment: You would add 2 output parameters to the procedure, assigning each the value of @@ROWCOUNT after the respective inserts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options here depending on your needs.

Firstly you could toggle the [`NOCOUNT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259204%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) setting between your insert statements so the count for the inserts you're not interested in are ignored:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spFoo]

AS
BEGIN

set nocount on
    insert into test values (1, 'a')
    insert into test values (2, 'b')
set nocount off 
    insert into test values (3, 'c')


END
```

This will return 1 when called with `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Alternatively you could grab the number of rows affected by the last insert using [`@@ROWCOUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187316.aspx). You can select that back and use `ExecuteScalar` to get the result in C#:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spFoo]

AS
BEGIN

    insert into test values (1, 'a')
    insert into test values (2, 'b')
    insert into test values (3, 'c')

    select @@ROWCOUNT
END
```

You'll need to cast the result in this case as the return value of `ExecuteScalar` is `object`:

```
int affected = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
```